# Incorrect elimination of X in the inductive type "or":

Tags: coq

I am trying to define a relatively simple function on Coq:

```
    (* Preliminaries *)
    Require Import Vector.
    Definition Vnth {A:Type} {n} (v : Vector.t A n) : forall i, i < n -> A. admit. Defined.

    (* Problematic definition below *)
    Definition VnthIndexMapped {A:Type}
    {i o:nat}
    (x: Vector.t (option A) i)
    (f': nat -> option nat)
    (f'_spec:  forall x, x<o ->
                    (forall z,(((f' x) = Some z) -> z < i)) \/
                                   (f' x = None))
    (n:nat) (np: n<o)
    : option A
    :=
      match (f' n) as fn, (f'_spec n np) return f' n = fn -> option A with        
      | None, _ => fun _ => None
      | Some z, or_introl zc1  => fun p => Vnth x z (zc1 z p)
      | Some z, or_intror _  => fun _ => None (*  impossible case *)
      end.
```

And getting the following error:

```
Error:
Incorrect elimination of "f'_spec n np" in the inductive type "or":
the return type has sort "Type" while it should be "Prop".
Elimination of an inductive object of sort Prop
is not allowed on a predicate in sort Type
because proofs can be eliminated only to build proofs.
```

I think I understand the reason for this limitation, but I am having difficulty coming up with a workaround. How something like this could be implemented? Basically I have a function `f'` for which I have a separate proof that values less than 'o' it either returns `None` or a `(Some z)` where `z` is less than `i` and I am trying to use it in my definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to a problem like this: the *easy way* and the *hard way*.

The easy way is to think whether you're doing anything more complicated than you have to. In this case, if you look carefully, you will see that your `f'_spec` is equivalent to the following statement, which avoids `\/`:

```
Lemma f'_spec_equiv i o (f': nat -> option nat) :
   (forall x, x<o ->
                               (forall z,(((f' x) = Some z) -> z < i)) \/
                               (f' x = None))
    <-> (forall x, x<o -> forall z,(((f' x) = Some z) -> z < i)).
Proof.
  split.
  - intros f'_spec x Hx z Hf.
    destruct (f'_spec _ Hx); eauto; congruence.
  - intros f'_spec x Hx.
    left. eauto.
Qed.
```

Thus, you could have rephrased the type of `f'_spec` in `VnthIndexedMapped` and used the proof directly.

Of course, sometimes there's no way of making things simpler. Then you need to follow the hard way, and try to understand the nitty-gritty details of Coq to make it accept what you want.

As Vinz pointed out, you *usually* (there are exceptions) can't eliminate the proof of proposition to construct something computational. However, you *can* eliminate a proof to construct *another proof*, and maybe that proof gives you what need. For instance, you can write this:

```
Definition VnthIndexMapped {A:Type}
           {i o:nat}
           (x: Vector.t (option A) i)
           (f': nat -> option nat)
           (f'_spec:  forall x, x<o ->
                                (forall z,(((f' x) = Some z) -> z < i)) \/
                                (f' x = None))
           (n:nat) (np: n<o)
: option A
  :=
    match (f' n) as fn return f' n = fn -> option A with
      | None => fun _ => None
      | Some z => fun p =>
                    let p' := proj1 (f'_spec_equiv i o f') f'_spec n np z p in
                    Vnth x z p'
    end eq_refl.
```

This definition uses the proof that both formulations of `f'_spec` are equivalent, but the same idea would apply if they weren't, and you had some lemma allowing you to go from one to the other.

I personally don't like this style very much, as it is hard to use and lends itself to programs that are complicated to read. But it can have its uses...

Comment: the f_spec' statement was indeed overcomplicated. Thankfully it was defined by me and I was able to change it to simpler version you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you want to build a term by inspecting the content of `f'_spec`. This disjunction lives in `Prop`, so it can only build other `Prop`. You want to build more, something in `Type`. Therefore you need a version of disjunction that lives at least in `Set` (more generally in `Type`). I advise you replace your `Foo \/ Bar` statement with the usage of `sumbool`, which uses the notation `{Foo}+{Bar}`.

Comment: Thanks! What would be the other implications of using 'sumbool' instead of \/? Any potential problems?

Comment: Basically if I give you P: A \/ B, you can't tell if it A or B that its true. You just know one of them is. With {A}+{B}, you also get to know which one is true (because you can destruct the term).