# Assert a proposition on multiple witnesses

Tags: coq

Assume I have an existential proposition `P` about the natural numbers, for example

```
Definition P (n : nat) : Prop
:= exists k:nat, True.
```

Assume also that I have proved `P` for all numbers,

```
Lemma allP : forall n : nat, P n.
Proof.
  intros. exists 0. trivial.
Defined.
```

Then I have a witness `k` for all `n` (`k` is always 0 in the previous example) and I want to assert something about all `k`s, such as

```
Definition allWitnessesBelowOne : Prop
  := forall n : nat,
    match allP n with
    | ex_intro _ k _ => k <= 1
    end.
```

except this does not compile, I get the following error :

```
Incorrect elimination of "allP n" in the inductive type "ex":
the return type has sort "Type" while it should be "Prop".
Elimination of an inductive object of sort Prop
is not allowed on a predicate in sort Type
because proofs can be eliminated only to build proofs.
```

I don't understand what is of sort `Type` here, everything looks in `Prop`. I am only trying to build a proof, why isn't Coq happy ? In my complete problem, `P` is much more complicated and it does make sense to prove something about all witnesses.

Comment: This is `Prop` that is in `Type`! `k <= 1` has type `Prop` which is not in `Prop`. Instead, for instance, `I` is a proof of `True` which is in `Prop`. I don't known how to solve your problem, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on @eponier's comment, when you write

```
Definition allWitnessesBelowOne : Prop
  := forall n : nat,
    match allP n with
    | ex_intro _ k _ => k <= 1
    end.
```

you are actually writing

```
Definition allWitnessesBelowOne : Prop
  := forall n : nat,
    match allP n return Prop with
    | ex_intro _ k _ => k <= 1
    end.
```

When you have `return Prop`, the return type `Prop` has type `Type`, while it must have type `Prop` to satisfy the elimination restriction.  Basically, if you lift this restriction, you make Coq inconsistent with classical logic.  See, for example, [the official documentation of `Prop`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/cic.html#inference-prop), [Incorrect elimination of X in the inductive type "or":](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261254/incorrect-elimination-of-x-in-the-inductive-type-or), or [CPDT on universes](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Universes.html).

Another way of looking at this is that, if you do not have any axioms, it must be possible to interpret all `Prop`s as either the singleton set (if they are true) or the empty set (if they are false).  There is no non-constant function out of a singleton set, so you cannot define any interesting properties over a proof of `exists k : nat, True`.

The simplest way to fix this is to stop using `Prop`.  Instead use sigma (`sig`) types to say:

```
Definition P (n : nat)
:= { k : nat | True }.

Lemma allP : forall n : nat, P n.
Proof.
  intros. exists 0. trivial.
Defined.

Definition allWitnessesBelowOne : Prop
  := forall n : nat,
    match allP n with
    | exist _ k _ => k <= 1
    end.
```

An alternative definition of this last one is

```
Definition allWitnessesBelowOne : Prop
  := forall n : nat,
    proj1_sig (allP n) <= 1.
```

---

The other thing you can do is that you can do everything continuation passing style:

```
Definition P (n : nat) : Prop
:= exists k:nat, True.

Lemma allP : forall n : nat, P n.
Proof.
  intros. exists 0. trivial.
Defined.

Lemma allWitnessesBelowOne_cps
      (n : nat)
      (Result : P n -> Prop)
  : (forall k pf, k <= 1 -> Result (ex_intro _ k pf))
    -> Result (allP n).
Proof.
  unfold allP; intro H.
  apply H; repeat constructor.
Defined.
```

Here, `Result` determines the `Prop` that you'll ultimately be proving.  This lemma says that whenever you're trying to prove a `Result` about `allP n`, you can assume that you're proving a `Result` about a value that is `<= 1`.  This is rather complicated, though, so I would suggest just dropping `Prop` if you can manage it.

Comment: Beautiful answer, thanks. Unfortunately I cannot drop `Prop`, because my existentials come from limits of sequences, `Un_cv` ie `forall epsilon : R, exists N:nat,... `. I have proved that the sequence converges and I need to build another sequence from that : the witnesses given for each `epsilon = 1/n`. I have seen that the standard library hacked the real axioms `completeness` and `total_order_T` to magically decide infinite properties. That would indeed make the `exists N:nat` a sigma-type, but I'd like to avoid that hack if I can.